# Why can I not change Custom Logo dimension attributes, via add_theme_support?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress website, where I am currently trying to call a Custom Logo into the `header.php` file.

I have managed to successfully do this, by entering the following into the `functions.php` file (as per WordPress Codex):

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
    'height'      => 100,
    'width'       => 400,
    'flex-height' => true,
    'flex-width'  => true,
    'header-text' => array( 'site-title', 'site-description' ),
) );
```

I then inserted `<php the_custom_logo(); ?>` into the `header.php` file, which has successfully called the Custom Logo.

I also tried calling the Custom Logo, by inserting the following Conditional Tag into the `header.php`, to see if this had any effect:

```
<?php
    if ( function_exists( 'the_custom_logo' ) ) {
        the_custom_logo();
    }
?>
```

That said, the Custom Logo does not seem to respond to any changes in the 'height' and 'width' attributes, when modified in the above code.  I know I can do this via CSS but wondering what I could be doing wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you regenerate your thumbnails then the new image size will show.  Use a plugin like [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) to selectively re-create the new image size through the Media Browser.  When you add a new image size via the `add_theme_support` function you always need to regenerate the thumbnails to create the image size.  This functions just registers the image size.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I have tried this but unfortunately, had no effect on the Custom Logo Dimensions.

Comment: Try the custom code the suggest on the wordpress.org sit to see what size it's returning.  $custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
$logo = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $custom_logo_id , 'full' );   https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/custom-logo/

Comment: Have just tried your suggested code, from Codex.  This does work, though the code in the `functions.php` still has no effect.  I guess I will just use `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` parameters, to adjust the dimension.  I did notice that the custom code does strip the `<img>` Element, of it's `alt` Attribute, which is something I will need to figure.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm sure there's a filter to add the alt tag back in.  Quick google search and 'post_thumbnail_html' came up.  You're welcome :)